# Can't find solutions to an equation involving a variable in eigenvalues

Tags: equation-solving, control-systems

In control sytems we know that a system is of order 2 if there are two different eigenvalues such that they ratio is 10. In this case I want to find the controller gain that makes the above possible. So, let's say the first root is $\lambda_1(k_c)$ while another root is $\lambda_2(k_c)$. I want to find the kc such that
$
\lambda_1(k_c)=10\lambda_2(k_c)$

By the way, of course that we have to see the real part of each eigenvalue, it doesn't make sense to look to the imaginary part.

So far I have the following:

```
AAstable = {{-64.383, 0, -22.35, 0, (36193 kc)/200}, {0, 0, 
    27.65, -50, (36193 kc)/200}, {1788, -2212, 0, 0, -1490 kc}, {0, 
    4000, 0, -333.333, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -0.1, 0}};
NSolve[Re[Eigenvalues[AAstable]] == 10 Re[Eigenvalues[AAstable]], kc]
```

Mathematica returns just a bunch of things that doesn't make any sense:

```
> {{Re[Root[System`ReduceDump`P$53239[1], 4]] -> 0.,   
> Re[Root[System`ReduceDump`P$53239[1], 3]] -> 0.,
```

Comment: Mathematica says there is no solution for real `kc`. You can try  `NSolve[re==10 re &&Element[kc,Reals],kc]` which gives `{}`

Comment: But I think there is something wrong.. In fact let $k_c=17.603$. The eigenvalues are $\{-11.1259, -111.26 - j484.519 , -111.26 + j484.519 , -82.0349 -  j167.054 , -82.0349 + j167.054 \}$. Clearly, $\frac{11.1259}{111.26}\approx 10$. So there should be any solution... (by the way I found that $k_c$ by looking the RootLocus but I need a better approximation than the graphic one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often solve these sorts of problems by defining objective functions that are 0 whenever the condition we want is met. I'm not sure exactly which eigenvalues you want to have a ratio of 10. The following objective function is 0 whenever any ratio is 10, but you can modify it as you need.

```
allRatios[kc_] := With[
    {e = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Re@Eigenvalues[AAstable[kc]], Chop]},
        Outer[#1/#2 &, e, e]
]
objective[kc_] := Min[(allRatios[kc] - 10)^2]
```

Now you can use `NMinimize`, `FindRoot`, or `FindMinimime` to find the zeros of `objective`:

```
FindMinimum[objective[x], {x, 10}]
```

If you play around with starting positions you will find solutions of either `17.6032` or `13.3927`. You also occasionally get warnings about machine precision limits. The best way to check what is going on since the problem is only one dimensional is just to make a plot where we see the two solutions:

```
Plot[objective[x], {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image: solution]

We can also look at eg.

```
allRatios[17.60318522324276`] // MatrixForm
```

which gives

[image]

Edit: note you will need to change `AAstable` to be a function of `kc` to make the above code work.

Comment: What do you mean with change AAstable to be a function of kc? Is it enough to write AAstable[kc_] ? Because it doesn't seem to work with that. EDIT: it was just me. Using Clear[AAstable] made it work.

Answer (score 2):

A graphical way to approach this would be to use `RootLocusPlot`.

Once you set it up, you can 'see' the effects of changing $kc$. The real pole moves to the left and the two pairs of complex poles move to the right (and will eventually destabilize the system if $kc$ is increased too much).

The ratio of 10 can be achieved twice. As $kc$ is increased to $\approx 13.5$, the real pole moves to $\approx -8$ and the real part of one complex pair moves to $\approx -80$. Then as kc becomes $\approx$ 17.5 the real pole has moved further left to $ \approx-11$ and the other complex pair has moved right with it's real part at $ \approx-110$. (I had a little fun playing around with the `Manipulate`.)

```
AAstable = {{-64.383, 0, -22.35, 0, (36193 kc)/200}, {0, 0, 
27.65, -50, (36193 kc)/200}, {1788, -2212, 0, 0, -1490 kc}, {0, 
4000, 0, -333.333, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -0.1, 0}};

tfm = 1/CharacteristicPolynomial[AAstable, s]
```

> [image]

```
Manipulate[RootLocusPlot[tfm, {kc, 0, 200}, FeedbackType -> None, 
AspectRatio -> 1, GridLines -> {{-110, -11}, None}, 
PoleZeroMarkers -> "ParameterValues" -> {kVal}], {kVal, 0, 200, 0.5}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that equates the characteristic polynomials.

```
(s + p) (s + 10 p + c I) (s + 10 p - c I) (s^2 + a s + b) + 
CharacteristicPolynomial[AAstable, s];

CoefficientList[%, s];
sols = NSolve[%, {p, c, a, b, kc}, Reals]
```

> [image]

```
DeleteDuplicates[kc /. sols]
```

> {13.3927, 17.6032}